# Spacetime as a medium for electromagnetic waves?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, aether, bohmian-mechanics

We typically break waves into two separate types mechanical waves and electromagnetic waves and treat them entirely differently based primarily on the observation that electromagnetic waves don't require a medium, meaning that the would travel un impeded through even a perfect vacuum. As I understand an electromagnetic wave is basically a wave that travels along two axis in which a changing electric field along one axis causes a changing magnetic field in the other and the wave then prorogates through continuous induction until it strikes something or collapses under entropy. But what if we assume that spacetime is the medium in which an electromagnetic field travels in the same way is the medium through which a compression wave travels then aren't they fundamentally both the same. We already know that gravitational fields can affect and bend electromagnetic waves. This is more commonly observed as gravitational lensing. I also wonder what implications there might be for pilot wave theory if you assume spacetime as the medium for electromagnetic waves.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_ether_theory

Answer (score 4):

In the sense that space is the "thing" through which light travels, sure, you're correct. The difference really comes from special relativity. If space is a medium, then any movement through space is movement with respect to that medium, and hence we would expect to see differences in the speed of light depending on our velocity with respect to said medium, precisely as occurs with sound waves.

This is, in fact, not the case, as was shown by the famous Michelson-Morley experiment. Instead, we find that the speed of light is a constant, completely independent of how we move through space. Not even the curvature of space can change the speed of light, only its direction. So in the end, you could call space a medium for light, and in some sense this would be accurate. However, space as a medium behaves differently than any other wave medium, and so you would be doing a disservice to the listener if you were to call space a medium.

Comment: The OQ is about spacetime, not space alone.

Comment: @dan replace everywhere "space" by "spacetime." Nothing about my answer changes. At its core, this question is equivalent to the one originally asked my Michelson-Morley and the physics community at that time. Only the language is somewhat different.